# Generate multiple bills in one go using crystal report and VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

I have written following code in VB6 to get required data from access and generate report :

```
Dim st As String
st = "{sales_order_details.order_no}>=" & Text1.Text & "  and {sales_order_details.order_no}<=" & Text2.Text & " and {sales_order_details.client_no}='" & Trim(Label2.Caption) & "'"
CR1.SelectionFormula = st
CR1.ReportFileName = frm_open.crname & "\" & "bill.rpt"
CR1.ReportSource = crptReport
CR1.Action = 2
```

Name of the rpt file is bill.rpt and here I can filter the data using `order_no`,  for example display the bills from order no 4 to 10.

But problem here is that only bill of order no 4 is generated. Instead it should generate 7 bills from order no 4 to 10.

Generate clause is  :

```
"{sales_order_details.order_no}>=4  and 
{sales_order_details.order_no}<=10 and 
{sales_order_details.client_no}='535'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the others bills (from 5 to 10) clients no equal to 535?

When you change the clause  such as in the below, generated bill no is 5?

```
"{sales_order_details.order_no}>=5  and 
{sales_order_details.order_no}<=10 and 
{sales_order_details.client_no}='535'"
```

I think that you can copy the selection formula and paste directly into crystal report and you can test it.

Comment: How to test that can you elaborate more on this plz ? I am new to this thing